# Binding Mode(TwoWay) changes can be modified in Database?

Tags: wpf, sql-server, binding

When i modifying the data in text boxes in GUI they are changing but they are saving to database can any one help me... is this possible or not?

`<TextBox Height="130" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=admissionNote, Mode=TwoWay}"/>`

or do i need write any query for update to update in db? if so where in which event or method should i write
please suggest me i m new to wpf

Answer (score 2):

Write a query to update the db when value changes and execute this query inside the setter of the 'admissionNote' property